(combinatorics) Smirnov words with probability - frequency problem
It is known that GF of Smirnov words with probabilistic weighting over r-ary alphabet
$$ S(z) = \frac{1}{1-\sum\frac{p_jz}{1+p_jz}}$$
and it has a dominant singularity at the unique positive point $\rho$
$$ \sum_{j=1}^r \frac{p_j\rho}{1+p_j\rho} = 1$$
the number of n-sized Smirnov words is
$$ [z^n]S(z) \sim \left(\sum\frac{p_j}{(1+p_j\rho)^2}\right)^{-1}\rho^{-n-1}$$
The jth letter appears with asymptotic frequency
$$ q_j = \frac{1}{Q}\frac{p_j}{(1+p_j\rho)^2}, \space\space Q :=\sum_{j=1}^r \frac{p_j}{(1+p_j\rho)^2}$$
< Citation :  "Analytic Combinatorics" by Phillippe Flajolet, Robert Sedgewick, p262~263 >

I can't understand the $q_j$, even though it is quite intuitive.
When it comes to the average number(frequency) of jth letter in a n-sized Smirnov word,
I think $$0\frac{n_0}{N} + 1\frac{n_1}{N} + 2\frac{n_2}{N} + ... k\frac{n_k}{N} + ...$$
where $n_k$ means the number of  k occurences of jth letter in a n-sized Smirnov word, and N total number of a n-sized Smirnov word. ($N=\sum n_k$)
So, taking $p_j$ as a variable ("Marker") $$N = \rho^{-n-1}(\sum\frac{p_j}{1+p_j\rho})^{-1}, \space\space 0 n_0+1 n_1+2 n_2 +... = \rho^{-n-1}\times p_j \times \frac{d}{dp_j}\left((\sum\frac{p_j}{1+p_j\rho})^{-1}\right) $$
Then, I could get the value Q above, but failed to get $q_j$. I might be wrong somewhere.
Can anyone explain how to get Q and $q_j$?

@ Jean Marie
"Analytic Combinatorics" by Phillippe Flajolet, Robert Sedgewick, p262~263

Please define all notation before first use.  What does $S(z)$ represent?  I cannot understand what the first sentence is saying.  What is "GF of Smirnov words"?  What does "I think  [formula]" mean?  I would not know how to interpret "I think 7".  Something like "I think x=7" would make sense to me, but not "I think 7" or "I think x".
